# How to find a segmentation fault in C code?

Tags: c, segmentation-fault

```
#include<stdio.h>
#include<stdlib.h>
#include<string.h>

int main()
{
  char *ptr1="abcdef";
  ptr1 = ptr1 +(strlen(ptr1)-1);

  printf("%c",--*ptr1--);
  printf("%c",--*--ptr1); 
  printf("%c",--*(ptr1--));
  printf("%c",--*(--ptr1));
  printf("%c",*ptr1);

  return 0;
}
```

Above code throws segmentation fault error. Could someone help me understand the reason behind it?

Comment: The reason is a crappy, unreadable code, likely invoking undefined behavior.

Comment: BTW, it won't even compile.

Comment: Please explain me breafly

Comment: It compiles but throws this error at run time.

Comment: Where's declared the variable `ptr1`? What the use of this code!?

Comment: It *cannot* compile as `ptr1` is undefined

Comment: It doesn't compile because the variable `ptr1` is not declared!

Comment: Please post compilable code. Did you mean `char *ptr1="abcdef";` ?

Comment: @RohitJangra This is non a minimum example. Please delete lines until there are as few lines as possible causing the segfault

Comment: @RohitJangra: what do you want to achieve with  --*--ptr1 and --*ptr1--? does it really make sense?

Answer (score 2):

Assuming there is a typo in your program and you actually have this:

```
char *ptr1 = "abcdef";
//       ^<<<<
```

instead of:

```
char *ptr = "abcdef";
```

You are trying to modify a string literal which yields in undefined behaviour, usually a segmentation fault.

Here is a minimal program that triggers the sort of segmentation fault you've got:

```
int main()
{
  char *string = "abcdef";
  *string = 'X';
}
```

You probably intended to do this:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>

int main()
{
  char string[] = "abcdef";
  char *ptr1 = string + (strlen(string) - 1);

  printf("%c", --*ptr1--);
  printf("%c", --*--ptr1);
  printf("%c", --*(ptr1--));
  printf("%c", --*(--ptr1));
  printf("%c", ptr1);

  return 0;
}
```

But there are still problems in this code:

1. Constructs like `--*ptr1--` or `--*--ptr1` are pointless. And maybe even undefined behaviour (not sure).
2. `printf("%c", ptr1);` yields in undefined behaviour because the format specifier `%c` doesn't match the type of `ptr1`. This would be correct: `printf("%p", ptr1);`.

Comment: Sorry for too many typos. I have corrected the code now. This question was asked in a coding puzzle test and none of the options in answer mentioned any error. Following are the options:                                                  
 a) ecbaa                 b) edcbb                c) fedaa                    d) Ecdbb

Comment: This puzzle was written by someone who doesn't understand undefined behavior.

Comment: Could you please explain undefined behaviour breafly

Comment: I just wan't to know how the program internally works

Comment: @RohitJangra Click here: --> [Undefined behaviour](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Undefined_behavior)